# How to extract subscripts in mathematica and apply a function on them?

Tags: matrix, symbolic, subscript

For a bit of context, I am trying to evaluate an integration over Haar randm unitaries. I couldn't find any inbuilt function, so I am trying to implement a simple code for the Wingarten functtion  in mathematica. I have to take average over following type of matrix elements.
$$e^{-\beta (1)} u_{2,1} u_{3,1} \left(u_{1,1}\right){}^*\left(u_{2,1}\right){}^*$$
or
$$e^{-2 \beta (1)} u_{2,1}^2 \left(\left(u_{1,1}\right){}^*\right){}^2$$

where the exponential pre-factor can be ignored.
I am aware of the formula for such average as below,
[image]

So, my goal is to extract the values of a,b,c,d and their primed versions for each matrix elements and do the averaging using this formula. I tried doing pattern matching, but I couldn't figure out a proper way to identify and distinguish those subscripts. Besides, i am trying to have a general function e.g I may have terms that look like

$$e^{-\beta (1)} u_{2,1} u_{3,1} \left(u_{1,1}\right){}^* \left(u_{2,1}\right){}^* u_{1,2} u_{4,1}$$

or something with higher power of terms. There are formulas  similar to B2 (product of delta) for those cases too, but I can't figure out a systematic way to extract these subscripts and evaluate the integral using such formula in Mathematica. I thought of defining $U$ with $U[[1,2]]$ elements instead of subscript variables, but there also I suppose pattern matching is the only way to extract the indices when encountering terms like below,
$$e^{-\beta (1)} u[[2,1]] u[[3,1]] \left(u[[1,1]]\right){}^* \left(u[[2,1]]\right){}^*$$

Any help will be much appreciated. I am not very well-versed with Mathematica, please excuse me if this is a straightforward technique to implement. I couldn't generalise the existing answers on extracting subscript variables as my case involves power of variables and I want to distinguish between subscript of conjugates. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am not sure if this meets your needs, but subscripts can be easily replaced. E.g.: `Subscript[u, i] /. i->q` will result in `Subscript[u, q]`

Comment: Thanks @DanielHuber. Yeah, subscripts can be replaced, but here I want to extract subscripts from a term.